# Jquery rare functions

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery in my website .Unfortunately i'm new to jquery and known  50% of it .

but my seniors are telling me the tricky functions in jquery  when i worked harder for the logic .

I decided to know the list of that type tricky functions .
or a URL.

can any one give me that list ??
i fully revised the Jquery afficial Ui site .

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. Sounds like you're after a [jQuery cheat sheet](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/cheatsheet/).

Answer (score 0):

Cheatsheet:
http://futurecolors.ru/jquery/

Alternative documentation:
http://jqapi.com/

Deconstructed:
http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/